# Find bases for the row space, column space, and null space of A, and verify the rank + nullity theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given a problem and I am confused on how to get started. I am supposed to find the bases for the row space, column space, and null space of this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&...&2\\-4&⋱&3\\6&...&1 \end{bmatrix}

And then I need to verify the rank + nullity theorem. But it seems like the matrix is incomplete. Am I missing something?

Comment: If this is all you got, then the question does seem unanswerable in its present form. By any chance is it possible that the $\text{ }\dots\text{ }$ and $\text{ }\ddots\text{ }$ represent zeroes?

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data My professor was not specific. I guess I'll just have to ask him for further clarification.

Comment: It's usual to omit the zeroes from a matrix.